# Keep track of friends signing up with Facebook in Android App

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an Android App and using Facebook Login to let user sign up using their Facebook Accounts.

I am a beginner, so wanted to know how to keep track of user's friends signing up on my application and accordingly push notify both users. I am adding a timeline, so I want to show user posts from his social circle only.

**Resolution:** We are now considering using Invite Friends in latest version of Facebook Graph API.

Comment: I don't get it why people here didn't like this question. I said I am a beginner, but now it seems as those who downvoted think themselves too smart and knowledgeable but can't answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook did an update a while back , I dont recall which version of the SDK or Graph API (Graph API 2.0 maybe?) this took effect in but you really cant do that kind of thing anymore. Now when you request the list of friends for the user the user ID for the friend that is returned in that list is now randomly generated and not their real account ID.

So when a friend that was pulled in from another user attempts to login with your app the ID you get for them is entirely different. The only real way to do this would be to then name match really but that is entirely unreliable in most cases.

**EDIT** 
This only behaves this way for games or for using the tagging api. Not for general friends list request.

Comment: that´s not how it works. you don´t get ANY data (not even any ID) if the friend did not authorize your app. except for inviting users to a game or for tagging, but even then you only get a tagging token or an invite token.

Comment: Thta is correct luschn. I was operating under the assumption that tagging was being used. Shouldnt have assumed that. My bad. Thanks for correcting me